# Facebook Logout

Tags: php, facebook

Hello i am trying to logout using file_get_contents.

Here is my code

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("http://www.facebook.com/logout.php"); ?>
```

i am not able to logout From Facebook .

Can AnyBody Help

Thanks

Comment: I think that this is a valid question. Rajat, Facebook blocks your request because the user_agent is not set. Before your `file_get_contents` line, set the user agent with a line like `ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)');`  Of course, you'll need credentials in the query string like Rijk suggests

Answer (score 2):

Logging out involves a lot more than doing a simple HTTP request. For one, you need the session id of the user you're trying to log off. When you execute this code, your server is actually the one doing the request, not the user using your system (and logged onto Facebook). So Facebook has no idea who you're trying to logout.

If you really want to do this, you should set up a Curl session, and pass the session id. But easier is, to provide a link to the user. If they go to the URL, their session id is passed automatically.

Comment: i have Session id . how to setup Curl session Please tell

Comment: Here's a tutorial: http://www.smooka.com/blog/2009/07/24/maintaining-php-session-when-using-curl/

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the very beginning of your website page

```
session_start();

if($_GET['logoutfrmfb']=="logout")
{
   unset($_SESSION['fb_{your app id}_code']);
   unset($_SESSION['fb_{your app id}_access_token']);
   unset($_SESSION['fb_{your app id}_user_id']);
}
```

Find and edit the following lines in src/base_facebook.php (probably lines 506-515)

```
  public function getLogoutUrl($params=array()) {
 return $this->getUrl(
   'www',
   'logout.php',
   array_merge(array(
     'next' => $this->getCurrentUrl().'?logoutfrmfb=logout',
     'access_token' => $this->getAccessToken(),
   ), $params)
   );
  }
```

works for me!